# EL wont get my property in my Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, javabeans

The error im getting is:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'Beans.ReservationBean' does not have the property 'getFirstName'.
Im trying to access my Bean in order to get the value
My bean has getters and setters with a parameter-less constructor. Has all the variable defines also.

```
public ReservationBean{

 String FirstName

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}
    }
```

This is my JSP page trying to get the property.

```
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td>${RB.FirstName}</td></tr>
```

This is my servlet code passing the bean as an object.

```
request.setAttribute("RB", RB);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Confirmation.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, try to name your variables starting with a lowercase, like firstName instead of FirstName. This will ensure your code is JavaBeans compliant which is important for EL.

Comment: I just did. Still no difference.

Comment: Can you edit and paste the refactored code?

Comment: Please rename FirstName to firstName

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your help. Never knew EL was so picky. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a `getFirstName()` in the code you pasted. Could that be it?

Comment: RB.FirstName will translate to the method RB.getfirstName() being called, which doesnt exist (note the case). Refactor your bean to be JavaBeans compliant and you'd be good.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the getter for the FirstName field `getFirstName`.  In EL, when you specify a property name, it ends up calling the getter for that property. Java is not able to find the method and so you are getting a PropertyNotFoundException exception. Also, use camelCase for field-name so in your case the field should be named firstName.
The generic syntax for a bean would be something like this:

```
private {type} fieldName;

public {type} getFieldName() {
 return (this.fieldName);
}
public void setFieldName({type} fieldName) {
 this.fieldName = fieldName;
}
```

Let me know how it goes.